# How to prevent duplication while creating multiple similar jButtons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I'm trying to learn about java GUI , and I can't seem but notice that there is a lot of duplication going around when trying to create multiple similar buttons. For example in this piece of code :

```
JButton btnAddCar = new JButton("Add Car");
btnAddCar.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
btnAddCar.setBounds(5, 5, 355, 155);
addInternalFrame.getContentPane().add(btnAddCar);

JButton btnAddHybridCar = new JButton("Add Hybrid Car");
btnAddHybridCar.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
btnAddHybridCar.setBounds(5, 165, 355, 155);
addInternalFrame.getContentPane().add(btnAddHybridCar);

JButton btnAddVan = new JButton("Add Van");
btnAddVan.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
btnAddVan.setBounds(5, 325, 355, 155);
addInternalFrame.getContentPane().add(btnAddVan);

JButton btnAddMotorcycle = new JButton("Add Motorcycle");
btnAddMotorcycle.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
btnAddMotorcycle.setBounds(5, 485, 355, 155);
addInternalFrame.getContentPane().add(btnAddMotorcycle);

JButton btnAddHybridMotorcycle = new JButton("Add Hybrid Motorcycle");
btnAddHybridMotorcycle.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
btnAddHybridMotorcycle.setBounds(5, 645, 355, 155);
addInternalFrame.getContentPane().add(btnAddHybridMotorcycle);

JButton btnAddCustomer = new JButton("Add Customer");
btnAddCustomer.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
btnAddCustomer.setBounds(365, 5, 355, 155);
addInternalFrame.getContentPane().add(btnAddCustomer);

JButton btnAddVIPCustomer = new JButton("Add VIP Customer");
btnAddVIPCustomer.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
btnAddVIPCustomer.setBounds(365, 165, 355, 155);
addInternalFrame.getContentPane().add(btnAddVIPCustomer);

JButton btnAddEmployee = new JButton("Add Employee");
btnAddEmployee.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
btnAddEmployee.setBounds(365, 325, 355, 155);
addInternalFrame.getContentPane().add(btnAddEmployee);

JButton btnAddDepartmentManager = new JButton("Add Department Manager");
btnAddDepartmentManager.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
btnAddDepartmentManager.setBounds(365, 485, 355, 155);
addInternalFrame.getContentPane().add(btnAddDepartmentManager);
```

Is there a shorter, aesthetic way of writing this code?

Comment: 1) `Don't use a null layout.` - Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. 2)  For your buttons to do anything you need to add an ActionListener to each button, so you really do need to create each button separately so you can add a different ActionListener to each button. 3) Don't keep creating new instances of the Font. A single Font object can be shared by all components.

Answer (score 1):

you could try to outsource the button creation into a method like this

Note: you might also have to add `addInternalFrame` as a parameter

```
private JButton createButton(String name, int x, int y){
      JButton button = new JButton(name);
      button.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
      button.setBounds(x, y, 355, 155);
      addInternalFrame.getContentPane().add(button);
      return button;
    }
```

and create your buttons with it

```
JButton btnAddCar = createButton("Add Car", 5, 5);
JButton btnAddHybridCar = createButton("Add Hybrid Car", 5, 165);
```

Comment: don't replicate mistakes in the question (manual sizing or locating)